# Implement an auto-refresh of the data in a Next.js page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to build a Dashboard that fetches data from a FastAPI API running on a Raspberry Pi. I want the dashboard to auto-refresh every few seconds or minutes to display real-time data (status of the Raspberry).

I want the call to the API to be in the server side so here is the challenge.

What I have now is a server side page that displays the data once and I have implemented the **getStaticProps** method setting a revalidate value of 5 seconds and I see that this does not work as I expected (probably I have not understood correctly the operation).

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const stats: object = CALL TO API

    return {
        props: {
            stats,
        },
        // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
        // - When a request comes in
        // - At most once every 5 seconds
        revalidate: 5, // In seconds
    }
}

export default function Stats({ stats }: {
    stats: any
}) {
    return (
        <pre>
            {stats.cpu_percent}<br />
            {stats.cpu_freq[0]}
        </pre>
    )
}
```

How can I get the data to refresh every X amount of time?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar it is not working because I can't use the method useEffect in a server side component.

Comment: You are using `getStaticProps`, so you are using the `pages` router of Next.js I guess. There you are allowed to use `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

[`revalidate: 5`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) means if a request comes 5s after the previous build, Next.js will re-generate the page instead of continuing to serve the one in cache from the previous build.

So this doesn't happen on its own. Something should trigger this request for `revalidate` to work. For example with:

```typescript
import { useEffect } from "react";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const stats: object = "CALL TO AP";

  return {
    props: {
      stats,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 2.5 seconds
    revalidate: 2.5, // In seconds
  };
}

export default function Stats({ stats }: { stats: any }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(async () => {
      /* 
       The first time reload is called, you would get the cached page,
       and in the background, Next.js will revalidate the page so that
       the next time reload is called, you get the updated page.
      */
      window.location.reload();
    }, 2500);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
  return (
    <pre>
      {stats.cpu_percent}
      <br />
      {stats.cpu_freq[0]}
    </pre>
  );
}
```